# Getting "$ is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting error message in firebug saying "TypeError: $ is not a function" and the code of small javascript underneath.

The full code is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#editvalue').click(function(e){$('#storedvalue').hide();$('#altervalue').show();});
  $('#savevalue').click(function(e){
var showNew = $('#file').val();
  $('#altervalue').hide();
  $('#storedvalue').show();
  $('#storedvalue span').text(showNew);
 });
</script>
```

Can anyone help me with this? I am not into javascript programming. Thanks in advance!

Edit: This is what sits in my head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/sfm_validatorv7.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/sfm_validate_jobform.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/rollover_images.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slideshow/fadeslideshow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/setslides.js"></script>
```

Do I need to add one more line with just "jquery.js" and upload this file to a server or I am missing something here, looks like all is ok above, thats why I am asking for help.

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery to the page before running this script?

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or a plunkr? My guess is you forgot to load jQuery before calling it (the $).

Comment: Where is the "head section" in relation to the first snippet? The first line should suffice as far as including jQuery is concerned

Comment: @Jan Dvorak The first snippet of code is under the form in the body section, all the rest is defined in the head section

Comment: any chance you have called `jQuery.noConflict` and didn't tell us?

Comment: Please provide a small self-contained _complete_ example of your problem. Not just snippets that are not sufficient to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak Yes, there is JQuery.noConflict(), in fadeslideshow.js, can I safely remove it?

Comment: @user2664401 this could be the reason. What I would do, however, is to ditch the entire plugin as it's going to be low quality if it does _this_. Where did you get it from?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak That's the Fade In Slideshow v2.0 from www.dynamicdrive.com, I am working on a web redesign and that slider was already there, tbh it looks old and has some bugs, Im gonna change it for something nicer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You've tagged this `jQuery`. jQuery is a library that provides a function called `$`, but you have to include the script that provides the library before you can use it.

```
<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
```

For other options, see the [jQuery download](http://jquery.com/download/) page, with special attention to the section on using a CDN.

Answer (score 0):

1: include the script that provides the jQuery library and try;
2: find out that is there any other scripts contain this tag "$", you can use *jQuery* to instand of.